# ANOVA Repeated Measurements

Tags: r, anova

I calculate the Greenhouse-Geisser-Epsilon (based on the Box-Approximation for the distribution on quadratic forms) for the ANOVA of following linear model.

```
Y<-data.frame(response=c(10,19,27,28,9,13,25,29,4,10,20,18,5,6,12,17),
               treatment=factor(rep(1:4,4)),
               subject=factor(rep(1:4,each=4)))
fit<-lm(response~treatment,Y)
anova(fit)
```

Is there a way to use R-packages like car or ez to get the GG-Epsilon for the approximate distribution of the test statistic which is used by the anova above.

I only know how to get the GG-Epsilon for the distribution of test statistic which is used in the following ANOVA:

```
ezANOVA(pigeon, dv=.(response), wid=.(subject), within=.(treatment), detailed=T)
```

But this test statistic is made up of different quadratic forms than the statistic which is used in the first example by the anova function.